# How do I match all "and" using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need an ActiveRecord query to match ALL items in a `params[]` array.

My current method gives results based on finding any of the tags, not "MATCH ALL"

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags

    def self.filter_by_params(params)
        scoped = self.scoped
        scoped = scoped.includes(:tags).where(:tags => {:id => params[:t]}) if params[:t]
        scoped
    end
end
```

I was attempting to write it something like below, but it gives me no results. Can someone can set me in the right direction? Is there a way to say `" AND "`?

```
def self.filter_by_params(params)
    scoped = self.scoped.includes(:tags)
    params[:t].each do |t|
        scoped = scoped.where(:tags => {:id => t})
    end
    scoped
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right the `params[:t]` will be an array of IDs. If that's the case you can do:

```
def self.filter_by_params(params)
  scoped = self.scoped
  scoped = scoped.tags.find_all_by_id(params[:t])
  scoped
end
```

Or just:

```
def self.filter_by_params(params)
  tags.find_all_by_id(params[:t])
end
```

Comment: Yes, it will just be an array of ID#'s... however, your solution is not working for me...

Comment: I am getting the message ***undefined local variable or method `tags' for #<Class:0x007fbded6a70b8>*** when i try your solution #2

Comment: also, if i just try it direct in the controller: @products = Product.tags.find_all_by_id(params[:t]) i get ***undefined method `tags' for #<Class:0x007fbdeb9a08e8>***

Comment: Am I correct in saying that this can't be done when you have multiple products... @products.tags.find_all versus product.tags.find_all

Answer (score 0):

you sould use :joins instead of :includes

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags

    def self.filter_by_params(params)
        scoped = self.scoped
        scoped = scoped.joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:id => params[:t]}) if params[:t]
        scoped
    end
end
```

Comment: This still does not "match all", if it finds any of the tags in the params it returns it